# Creating new columns by splitting a variable into many variables (in R)

Tags: r, string, split, dataframe

I want to create new columns by splitting a vector in a data frame.

I have such a data frame:

```
YEAR Variable1 Variable2 
2009 000000    00000001
2010 000000    00000001
2011 000000    00000001
2009 000000    00000002
2010 000000    00000002
2009 000000    00000003
...
2009 100000    10000001
2010 100000    10000001
...
2009 100000    10000011
....
```

As you can see Variable2 is related to Variable 1 (Variable2=Variable1+last two digits: e.g. 01, 02, 03... indicating subcategories). I want to split Variable2 in so many variables as the subcategories are. The result should be:

```
YEAR Variable1 Variable2 Variable3 Variable4 ... 
2009 000000    00000001  0         0        
2010 000000    00000001  0         0
2011 000000    00000001  0         0
2009 000000    0         00000002  0
2010 000000    0         00000002  0
2009 000000    0         0         00000003
...
2009 100000    10000001  0         0     
2010 100000    10000001  0         0     
...
2009 100000    0         0         0       ...      10000011
```

How would you proceed? I thought I should try to recode Variable2 in a loop.. I tried by manipulating strings, but I didn´t solve the problem..

Comment: so depending upon the last two variable you want to create column and give value so there will be a total of  approximately 101 column is that waht you want

Comment: For example to the first element in Variable1 (000000) correspond 3 elements in Variable 2 (00000001, 00000002, 00000003) that should be rewritten in three different columns.. Every time that the last two digits in  an element in Variable2 are 01, that element remains in the column of variable two. When  the last two digits in  an element in Variable2 are 02 that element goes to Variable3 (or if Variable3 doesn´t exist, it is created). In this way new variables are created only if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work. First let's build the data.

```
values <- paste0("0000000", 1:4)
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(val = sample(values, 10, replace = TRUE))
```

A for loop is enough to define the new columns.

```
for(level_var in dt[, unique(val)]){
  dt[, eval(level_var) := ifelse(val == level_var, level_var, 0)]
}
```

Comment: Good answer, except you'll need to use `substr(eval(level_var), nchar(eval(level_var)) - 1, nchar(eval(level_var))) := ifelse(val == level_var, level_var, 0)` since it seems the OP wants `val = xxxxxxyy` to be the same new column for all possible prefixes of yy

Comment: There is still a little work need to be done the OP wants the output like variabl1,variable2,.....variable99

Comment: I understand what you mean.. What is "level_var"? I looked for documentation about the package "data.table" but I didn´t find anything about it. Thank you for the help! The code doesn´t work on my data yet.. But I´m working on it

Comment: `for (x in y)` creates a temporary variable `x` that iterates through the values of `y`. So in this case, `level_var` will iterate through the values of `dt[, unique(val)]`, which corresponds to the unique values in the `Variable2` column of your table.

Comment: ah ok! Got it! Dumb question!

Comment: `for (v in 1:length(unique(dt$Variable2))){`
`dt[paste('Variable', v+2, sep='')] =` `ifelse(dt$Variable2==unique(dt$Variable2)[v], unique(dt$Variable2)[v], 0)`
    `}`

Will do the same, but using a data.frame, and creating the desired "Variable3..VariableN" naming scheme for columns

Answer (score 1):

Using `reshape2`. A one-line solution. Another line if we'd like to remove the NA values.

```
library(reshape2)
df <- data.frame(YEAR=c(2009,2010,2011,2009,2010,2009,2009,2010,2009),
                 Var1=c('000000','000000','000000','000000','000000','000000','100000','100000','100000'),
                 Var2=c('0000001','0000001','0000001','0000002','0000002','0000003','1000001','1000001','1000011')) 
df <- dcast(df, YEAR + Var1 + Var2 ~ Var2, value.var = "Var2")[, -3]
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```

Result:

```
  YEAR   Var1 0000001 0000002 0000003 1000001 1000011
1 2009 000000 0000001       0       0       0       0
2 2009 000000       0 0000002       0       0       0
3 2009 000000       0       0 0000003       0       0
4 2009 100000       0       0       0 1000001       0
5 2009 100000       0       0       0       0 1000011
6 2010 000000 0000001       0       0       0       0
7 2010 000000       0 0000002       0       0       0
8 2010 100000       0       0       0 1000001       0
9 2011 000000 0000001       0       0       0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another suggestion. The code is somewhat longer, but I believe it does the trick, and I hope that it can be understood easily. I'm assuming that the original data is stored in a tab-separated file named 'data.dat'.
The output of the code is stored in the matrix 'new_matrix'. The entries are characters, but it shouldn't be a problem to convert them into integers if necessary.

```
data <- read.table('data.dat', sep='\t', header = TRUE, colClasses = "character")
var2 <- data[3]
nc <- nchar(var2[1,1])
last2 <-substr(var2[,1],nc-1,nc)
subcat <-levels(factor(last2))
mrows <- nrow(data)
mcols <- length(subcat)
varnames <-paste0("Variable",as.character(c(1:(mcols+1))))
new_matrix <- matrix(paste(replicate(nc,"0"),collapse=""),nrow=mrows,ncol=mcols+2)
colnames(new_matrix) <- c("YEAR",varnames)
new_matrix[,1]<-data[,1]
new_matrix[,2]<-data[,2]
for (i in 1:mcols) {
    relevant_rows <- which(last2 == subcat[i])
    new_matrix[relevant_rows,i+2]<-data[relevant_rows,3]
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach. Note that I choose to make the subcat dummy variables into binary indicator variables to reduce redundancy:

**Input:**

```
data <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
  year var1      var2
  2009 000000    00000001
  2010 000000    00000001
  2009 000000    00000002
  2010 000000    00000002
  2009 000000    00000003
  2009 100000    10000001
  2009 100000    10000004
  2010 100000    10000010                 
', colClasses = c('character', 'character', 'character'))
```

**Simplifying var2 column:**

```
subCat <- function(s) {
  substr(s, nchar(s) - 1, nchar(s))
}
data$var2 <- subCat(data$var2)
```

**Creating dummies:**

**Method 1:**

```
t <- table(1:length(data$var2), data$var2)
data <- cbind(data, as.data.frame.matrix(t))
data$var2 <- NULL
```

**Output:**

```
 year   var1 01 02 03 04 10
1 2009 000000  1  0  0  0  0
2 2010 000000  1  0  0  0  0
3 2009 000000  0  1  0  0  0
4 2010 000000  0  1  0  0  0
5 2009 000000  0  0  1  0  0
6 2009 100000  1  0  0  0  0
7 2009 100000  0  0  0  1  0
8 2010 100000  0  0  0  0  1
```

===========================================================

**Method 2:**

```
library(dummies)
data$var2 <- subCat(data$var2)
data3 <- cbind(data, dummy(data$var2))
data3$var2 = NULL
```

**Output:**

```
  year   var1 data01 data02 data03 data04 data10
1 2009 000000      1      0      0      0      0
2 2010 000000      1      0      0      0      0
3 2009 000000      0      1      0      0      0
4 2010 000000      0      1      0      0      0
5 2009 000000      0      0      1      0      0
6 2009 100000      1      0      0      0      0
7 2009 100000      0      0      0      1      0
8 2010 100000      0      0      0      0      1
```

===========================================================

**Method 3:**

```
dummies <- sapply(unique(data$var2), function(x) as.numeric(data$var2 == x))
data <- cbind(data, dummies)
data$var2 = NULL
```

**Output:**

```
  year   var1 X01 X02 X03 X04 X10
1 2009 000000   1   0   0   0   0
2 2010 000000   1   0   0   0   0
3 2009 000000   0   1   0   0   0
4 2010 000000   0   1   0   0   0
5 2009 000000   0   0   1   0   0
6 2009 100000   1   0   0   0   0
7 2009 100000   0   0   0   1   0
8 2010 100000   0   0   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
df <- data.frame(YEAR=c(2009,2010,2011,2009,2010,2009,2009,2010,2009),
                         Var1=c('000000','000000','000000','000000','000000','000000','100000','100000','100000'),
                         Var2=c('0000001','0000001','0000001','0000002','0000002','0000003','1000001','1000001','1000011'))

df <- mutate(df, tag=paste(YEAR, Var1, Var2, sep='-'))
df <- dcast(df, YEAR + Var1 + tag ~ Var2, fun.aggregate = NULL)
df$tag <- NULL
df <- apply(df, 2, function(x) sub('^(.*)-(.*)-', '', x))
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
df <- as.data.frame(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  YEAR   Var1 0000001 0000002 0000003 1000001 1000011
1 2009 000000 0000001       0       0       0       0
2 2009 000000       0 0000002       0       0       0
3 2009 000000       0       0 0000003       0       0
4 2009 100000       0       0       0 1000001       0
5 2009 100000       0       0       0       0 1000011
6 2010 000000 0000001       0       0       0       0
7 2010 000000       0 0000002       0       0       0
8 2010 100000       0       0       0 1000001       0
9 2011 000000 0000001       0       0       0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all these answers. I found the solution by combining the answer of Michele Usuelli and the comment to his answer of Synergist. I also learnt more about data.table

```
NbTabelle <- data.table(val=Netz)
attach(NbTabelle)
for(level_var in namesvec){
NbTabelle[, eval(level_var) := ifelse(substr(eval(val), 7, 8) == level_var, val, 0)]
}
```

Where namesvec is the variable names vector that I created from the previous generated tables, leaving apart the variable val.
I appreciated the generality of Synergist code, but for my purpose I needed only the last two digits.