# Model a data.table using more vectors as reference (in R)

Tags: r, string, loops, vector, data.table

A few days ago I asked this question: [Creating new columns by splitting a variable into many variables (in R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621089/creating-new-columns-by-splitting-a-variable-into-many-variables-in-r) . At the end I used this code:

```
NbTabelle <- data.table(val=Netz)
attach(NbTabelle)
for(level_var in namesvec){
NbTabelle[, eval(level_var) := ifelse(substr(eval(val), 7, 8) == level_var, val, 0)]
}
```

Now I want to modify this code to transform this table (it is only as example, the true table is huge!):

```
    year val_base     val       01       02       03       04
 1: 2008 000000   00000001 00000001        0        0        0
 2: 2008 000000   00000002        0 00000002        0        0
 3: 2008 000000   00000003        0        0 00000003        0
 4: 2009 000000   00000003        0        0 00000003        0
 5: 2008 000000   00000004        0        0        0 00000004
 6: 2009 111111   11111101 11111101        0        0        0
 7: 2010 111111   11111101 11111101        0        0        0
 8: 2011 111111   11111101 11111101        0        0        0
 9: 2012 111111   11111101 11111101        0        0        0
10: 2013 111111   11111101 11111101        0        0        0
11: 2014 111111   11111101 11111101        0        0        0
12: 2009 111111   11111102        0 11111102        0        0
13: 2010 111111   11111102        0 11111102        0        0
14: 2011 111111   11111102        0 11111102        0        0
15: 2012 111111   11111102        0 11111102        0        0
16: 2009 111111   11111103        0        0 11111103        0
17: 2010 111111   11111103        0        0 11111103        0
18: 2009 111111   11111104        0        0        0 11111104
19: 2010 111111   11111104        0        0        0 11111104
20: 2011 111111   11111104        0        0        0 11111104
```

Into this:

```
   year val_base      val       01       02       03       04
1  2008 000000   00000001 00000001 00000002 00000003 00000004
4  2009 000000   00000003        0        0 00000003        0
6  2009 111111   11111101 11111101 11111102 11111103 11111104
7  2010 111111   11111101 11111101 11111102 11111103 11111104
8  2011 111111   11111101 11111101 11111102        0 11111104
9  2012 111111   11111101 11111101 11111102        0        0
10 2013 111111   11111101 11111101        0        0        0
11 2014 111111   11111101 11111101        0        0        0
```

Indeed I´m interested in knowing how many variables 01, 02, etc... per year and per val_base there are (the next step will be the sum of the variables 01, 02, etc. per year).

I thought that I could solve the problem by nesting more ifelse functions inside a loop. My idea was something like:

```
for(level_var in namesvec){
  for(i in 1:19){
  dt2[, eval(level_var) := ifelse(substr(eval(val), 7, 8) == level_var, val, ifelse(eval(val[i]) != val[i+1],0,val[i]))]
 }
}
```

But it is wrong..

Comment: Why do you use `attach`? It should be avoided in general, but is really not necessary when working with data.table.

Comment: Are these numeric values or stings? If these are numbers, `unique(setDT(NbTabelle)[, lapply(.SD, sort, decreasing = TRUE), by = list(year, val_base)], by = c("year", "val_base"))` seem to give you what you need. And, as pointed by Roland, please don't use `attach`.

Comment: wouldn't make more sense to use dcast instead of loops? DT1 = NbTabelle[,.(year,val_base,val);  dcast(DT1, year ~ val). Instead of zeros you would get NAs though, but that could be easily changed if needed.

Comment: @AndresT That's a nice idea, but no where near the desired output. Something like `dcast(DT1, year + val_base ~ val)` will be closer but still needs some work (beside the `NA`s)

Comment: Thanks for the input @DavidArenburg. The year + val_base is definitely needed. For dealing with the NAs something like DT1[,lapply(.SD,function(x) ifelse(!is.na(x),x,0))] should do the trick. But then going back to your first point, are the variables strings or numbers. Perhaps splitting the val variable into the val_base and the last digits using stringr or regex processing would make the whole thing easier.

Comment: My variables are strings (that´s propably why my for loop didn´t work at all (?) ). Thank you for the help! The code that David Arenburg wrote works perfectly on my data. I also appreciated the suggestion of AndresT. I´m not very familiar to the data.table package... Why should `attach` be avoided in general?